# Add a loading spinner on top of a bootstrap 4 image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 page with an image that can be changed by the user interacting with several dropdowns. Based on the selected options, the image source is changed. The images are fairly large, so loading the requested image takes some time. I'd like to display a loading spinner on top of the image while the new image is being loaded, so the user knows that their action had some effect.

It seems like the built-in bootstrap spinners need their own div, so I thought a gif like this could work if placed on top of the image: https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp However, I'm not sure how to place it on top of the image and trigger the events necessary to show/hide it. Since my columns are not fixed-width, I want to display the spinner on top of the image rather than swapping the image source for the spinner, so all of the content remains in the correct positions.

Example code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto" style="background-color:red;">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto" style="background-color:green;" >
            <h2 class="header-2">Column 2</h2>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x350">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto" style="background-color:blue;">
            <h2>Column 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, right after the  tag add this:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Then add the style class for the `div` and image to your CSS:

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Then, add this javascript to your page (preferably at the end of your page, before your closing `</body>` tag, of course):

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
  });
</script>
```

Finally, adjust the position of the loading image and the `background-color` of the loading div with the style class.

This is it, should work just fine. But of course you have to have an `ajax-loader.gif` somewhere. Freebies [here](https://giphy.com/explore/loading). (Right-click > Save Image As...)

Comment: The spinner is displaying over the entire page, not over my image. See: https://www.codeply.com/p/x1EiL25vhm